# How to generate JavaDoc using buildr?

Tags: build, javadoc, buildr

I want to automatically generate the JavaDoc using buildr. I tried using the approach suggested in the official Guide PDF from the Homepage. However, it did not work.

```
define "SharedState_ebBP", :layout=>eclipse_layout do 
project.version = VERSION_NUMBER
project.group = GROUP
```

doc :windowtitle => "Abandon All Hope, Ye Who Enter Here", :private => true
  end

The error message is as follows:
RuntimeError: Don't know how to generate documentation from windowtitleAbandon ......

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax for setting the window title is

```
doc.using(:windowtitle => "Abandon All Hope", :private => true)
```

and with `end` on a line by itself.  However that in and of itself does not cause the `doc` task to get run automatically.

To automatically build the JavaDoc when you run `buildr` simply add to the end of your buildfile:

```
task :default => [:build, :doc]
```

This redefines the `default` task to first `build` and then `doc`.